# Dagger 2.11, difficulty when create new module for retrofit and rxjava

Tags: android, rx-java, dagger-2, android-mvp

Looking at some examples I was able to work with Dagger 2.11 for activities and fragments, however, I'm not getting any progress when creating modules for calls to Webservice using Retrofit + RxJava. Sorry if it is a repeated question, I have not found solution here.

Follow my application code below:

App.java

```
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        DaggerAppComponent.builder().create(this).inject(this);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        } else {
            Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
            Timber.plant(new FirebaseCrashReportingTree());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public AndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return activityDispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

AppComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AppModule.class})
interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<App> {


    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<App> {
    }
}
```

AppModule.java

```
@Module(includes = {AndroidInjectionModule.class})
abstract class AppModule {

    @Binds
    @Singleton
    abstract Application application(App app);

    @PerActivity
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainActivityModule.class)
    abstract MainActivity mainActivityInjector();
}
```

Comment: Please use english for title too

Comment: I'm sorry, @MatPag.

Comment: what's your question? it's not clear. If you need an example, you can check my boilerplate code for Dagger 2.11 https://github.com/savepopulation/di-espresso-demo

Comment: @savepopulation, my question it comes down to how to use retrofit + rxjava. Do I need to create a new module? How do I this?

Comment: where is retrofit and rxjava in this ?

Comment: @Benjamin, here you not have it, that's how my current structure is.

Comment: as it stands, this question is too broad and can't be answered

Comment: you have to create a module which provides retrofit. you do not need an extra module for RxJava. your services and return observable, single etc.. you can also check this repo https://github.com/savepopulation/dc-tracker it's in kotlin but you can convert it to java.

Comment: @savepopulation, the idea is this, but I could not make the minimum of this module and use it. Does not compile. Can you give me a light?

Comment: please check my repo in my previous comment.

Comment: @savepopulation, thanks. I based in your repository, one article at medium (https://proandroiddev.com/implementing-mvp-with-new-dagger-android-injection-api-773b13e1ef0) and little texts of internet. Now, my application it calling api with Retrofit and use RxJava. I'm sorry per ask one question for beginners. :)